# How do I run lintian from pbuilder-dist?

Tags: packaging, debian, pbuilder

I am using `pbuilder-dist` to build my packages for Debian unstable and Ubuntu Precise. I want to know how to run `lintian` (and possibly other commands) inside a certain chroot.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my machine.

Comment: Lintian i *think* can be run as its own command, if not, then you can run it at build-time, using pbuilder to build teh source package (create the source package with `debuild -S`), but I'm not entirely certain, so I'm not posting this as a true answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lintian can be run inside `cowbuilder` or `pbuilder` using hooks.
Several examples are available in `/usr/share/doc/pbuilder/examples/`

Just copy the hook you want to a directory:

```
mkdir ~/pbuilderhooks
cp /usr/share/doc/pbuilder/examples/B90lintian $HOME/pbuilderhooks
```

Then tell pbuilder to use the hooks in that directory:

```
echo "HOOKDIR=$HOME/pbuilderhooks/" >> ~/.pbuilderrc
```

And/or:

```
echo "HOOKDIR=$HOME/pbuilderhooks/" | sudo tee -a /etc/pbuilderrc
```

The first  is required if you intend to run `cowbuilder-dist` or `pbuilder-dist` without sudo; the latter if you intend to run `sudo cowbuilder` or `sudo pbuilder`.  Use tee -a to avoid overwriting the original /etc/pbuilderrc file.

Answer (score 0):

Running debuild -S will run lintian on the source.changes for you I believe.  Lintian is also run on the .changes file during the binary build.  Once you've built the binary and/or source package you can manually run lintian against either .changes file, just like this:

```
mfisch@caprica:~$ lintian libkqueue_1.0.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.changes
```

or

```
mfisch@caprica:~$ lintian libkqueue_1.0.4-2ubuntu1_source.changes
```

You may get different lintian errors or warnings from each build (source and binary).

If you're trying to move quicker, run pbuilder --login, install the build-deps and run your builds there, that saves you the start-up time from re-installing deps before each build.